# Deploying Client and Server to the same VM

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, web-applications, client-server

I have an application that has a `React` frontend and a `Python Flask` backend. The frontend communicates with the server to perform specific operations and the server api should only be used by the client.

I have deployed the whole application (Client and Server) to an Ubuntu virtual machine. The machine only has specific ports open to the public (5000, 443, 22). I have setup `Nginx` configuration and the frontend can be access from my browser via `http://<ip:address>:5000`. The server is running locally on a different port, 4000, which is not accessible to the public as designed.

The problem is when I access the client app and I navigate to the pages that communicate with the server via `http://127.0.0.1:4000` from the react app, I get an error saying connection was refused.
`GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on my browser.

When I ssh into the vm and run the same command through curl `curl http://127.0.0.1:4000/`, I get a response and everything works fine.

Is there a way I can deploy the server in the same vm such that when I access the client React App from my browser, the React App can access the server without problems?

Answer (score 1):

So after tinkering with this, I found a solution using Nginx. Summary is you run the server locally and use a different port say 4000 (not exposed to public), then expose your react app on the exposed port in this case 5000.

Then use a proxy in your Nginx config that redirects any call starting with `api` to the local host server running. See config below

```
server {
   #Exposed port and servername ipaddress
   listen 5000;
   server_name 1.2.3.4 mydomain.com;

   #SSL
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

   #Link to the react build   
   root /var/www/html/build;
   index index.html index.htm;

   #Error and access logs for debugging
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }

   #Redirect any traffic beginning with /api to the flask server
   location /api {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
   }
}
```

Now this means you need to have all your server endpoints begin with `/api/...` and the user can also access the endpoint from the browser via `http://<ip:address>:5000/api/endpoint`

You can mitigate this by having your client send a token the server and the server will not run any commands without that token/authorization.

I found the solution here and modified it to fit my specific need here
[Part two of solution](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project)

Other series in the solution can be found [Part one of solution](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project) and [Part three of solution](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react-router-flask-application)